# A problem on Degrees of Freedom

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

Degrees of freedom of a massless rod, moving freely in space with a speck which is constrained to move on it?

It seems massless rod is ideal
I am very confused how to regulate degrees of freedom. However, I know **Degrees of freedom** mean minimum number of coordinate to specify something.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is the speck constrained just to move up and down the rod, i.e. along a line, or can it also move around the circumference of the rod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rod has six degrees of freedom: X,Y,Z location of its center of mass, two degrees for the direction the axis points, and one degree for rotation around the axis. The speck can move anywhere on the surface of the rod (a two dimensional surface), giving another two degrees of freedom.  Presumably the speck is a dimensionless point, so does not have orientational degrees of freedom, which would otherwise give the speck an additional three degrees of freedom.  So, there are a total of eight degrees of freedom, or eleven if the speck has a size and shape.

Comment: Rod is massless nevertheless should we consider the center of mass?

Comment: Actually, any point rigidly attached to the rod serves the purpose as well as the center of mass.  It's just a way to say where the rod is in space.

Comment: Here the speck works as a constraint. Right!

Comment: Then what is the difference between rod and massless rod as a prospective of degrees of freedom??

Comment: There is no difference: an object has the ssme degrees of freedom whether it is massless or not.  If the problem were to count the degrees of freedom of a point on a rod-shaped *surface*, that's different.  In that case you need to decide if the surface is fixed in space or not, and how its orientation is constrained.  That is, is the surface merely a constraint, or is it an object.

Comment: Last question ..does the speck works here as a constrain ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I assume that the speck and the rod are objects that together comprise the system whose degrees of freedom you need to count.  The speck is not a constraint; rather, it is constrained to be on the rod's surface.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: please have  a look on this problem.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/579181/272209

Comment: You should re-pose that as a new question.

Comment: You should use what you learned from this problem to see if you can solve the other problem yourself.

Comment: Please have a look sir https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/579347/272209

Comment: Sir actually answer of this problem is $4$ in my book. Can you please suggest a good book to study this sort of problems?

Comment: I suggest that you simply search Google for explanations of degrees of freedom.  It seems that the problems in your book are very poorly posed!  What is a "rod", and what is a "speck"?  If the rod is fixed in space and is actually a dimensionless line, but the speck is, e.g., a sphere with three degrees of orientational freedom, then there is a total of four degrees of freedom.  In school I often answered problems like this by explaining all the possible interpretations, and answering each separately, but sometimes the professor penalized me for that kind of answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Sir! I'll follow what you said.(+1)

Answer (score 1):

Three coordinates $(x, y, z)$ are required to describe the pole's position. Two coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$ are required to describe the pole's orientation (think latitude and longitude). Finally, one coordinate is required to describe the position of the speck on the pole. That makes six total degrees of freedom.

Edit: To clarify, this answer assumes that the rod is infinitely thin. This appears not to be what the author intended, but I'll leave this answer here in case anyone finds it useful.