# How do you find the degrees of freedom of a rigid body moving parallel to a fixed plane surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

Find the degrees of freedom of a rigid body moving parallel to a fixed plane surface.

---

I know the definition of degrees of freedom which meant we need minimum number of coordinate to specify something.

---

Thoughts about this problem:  Since the rigid body moving parallel to the plane so we need two coordinates for translation motion along $X-axis$ and $Y-axis$.

And two coordinates for its orientation as we do in spherical coordinate.
Evidently, The answer will be $4$.

But in book answer is $3$. I am very confused. How it will be $3$?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

> Find the degrees of freedom of a rigid body moving parallel to a fixed plane surface.

is the exact problem statement, then I think it is not well posed.  If the given answer is 3, then I assume the rigid body is something like a hockey puck that slides on the plane surface.  In that case, the degrees of freedom would include only its x,y position and its rotation on an axis perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: Btw, In which case my assumptions would be true? Leave the answer of the book.

Comment: No.  A hockey puck constrained to a surface has only one rotational degree of freedom.

Comment: If the rigid body were , e.g., a sphere rolling on the surface, then it would have three degrees of orientational freedom plus the two degrees of positional freedom.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!